# Download unity bin.Data assets

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have create a custom `UnityPlayerActvity` and now I just wonder that is it possible to host those assets file on my own server and download it somewhere on sdcard or data path to make the APK size as light as possible? I know how to download and unzip the file but I don't know how to tell `UnityPlayerActvity` to read the data from the new path instead of APK assets path!

Any ideas on how accomplish this?

Comment: What type of data is that?

Comment: Your UnityPlayerActivity is from a plugin or from your own Unity  project apk?

Comment: Yep.  Addressable Components

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, do you wish to load external assets bundle from local or server at runtime to optimize the app size?

1. Use the Unity Web Request if your version is later than 2018 (example code in documentation)i.e **`version > 2018`**
   [UnityWebRequest-Downloading AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-DownloadingAssetBundle.html) or [Unity Web Request AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.html)
2. Use the "**WWW class**" to load and save files locally if your unity version is earlier than 2018 i.e **`version < 2018`** e.g loading sample.jpg from local directory.

   ```
   var url = "\localfiles\sample.jpg";
       function Start () {
       var www : WWW = new WWW (url);
       yield www;
       renderer.material.mainTexture = [url]www.texture;[/url]
   }
   ```

Method 2: *can pose a security issue if your files get manipulated from client-side after download.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **Addressable Asset System**?

> The Addressable Asset System provides an easy way to load assets by
>   “address”. It handles asset management overhead by simplifying content
>   pack creation and deployment.
>
> The Addressable Asset System uses asynchronous loading to support
>   **loading from any location** with any collection of dependencies. Whether
>   you are using direct references, traditional asset bundles, or
>   Resource folders, addressable assets provide a simpler way to make
>   your game more dynamic.

It’s easy to [get started](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.1/manual/AddressableAssetsGettingStarted.html) in a new project, or follow the [Migration Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.1/manual/AddressableAssetsMigrationGuide.html) if you would like to [upgrade an existing project](https://unity.com/how-to/simplify-your-content-management-addressables?_ga) to take advantage of addressables. Unity3d also provide [example projects](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Addressables-Sample) for basic and advanced usage on GitHub.

**Useful links:**

- [Host Addressables with the Google Cloud](https://medium.com/@badgerdox/addressablesgooglecloud-7933452318ea)
- [Host Addressables with the AWS](https://medium.com/@badgerdox/howtoawsaddressables-f26803e3b0a)
- [Host Addressables with the Azure](https://medium.com/@badgerdox/how-to-use-unity3d-addressable-assets-with-an-azure-blob-fcf4ec5683c7)